# AWS CloudFormation Run Script on DeleteStack

Tags: unix, aws-cloudformation

In AWS CloudFormation I know of using `UserData` in my `EC2::Instance` to run some code on creation.  Is there any functionality similar to how `UserData` runs, but on `DeleteStack`?  I found `DeletionPolicy` but the more looks like "what to do on delete, keep or actually delete" instead of a more open ended scripting space.

The only thing I see that might work is [`cfn-hup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html) but I don't know if it's worth exploring more.

Comment: Are you using autoscaling groups? then look at autoscaling hooks.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran Haven't gotten to autoscaling groups yet, still getting the early bits stable before moving onto the bigger arch.  Still a small stack without the time/need for autoscale (for now at least).

Comment: Ok, There is no such facility as far I know but in Linux, you can simply drop your script at `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` and it would trigger when the instance is shutting down.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue and as mentioned in previous comments there is no support in cloudformation, keeping the script in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` as suggested by Sudharsan Sivasankaran did not work for me but I did found the solution which involved creating a linux service, below are the steps:

This is a workaround and worked perfectly fine for me:
let's call the script to be run before shutdown as `the_script.sh`

1. Move the script to `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` # this is not required, you can keep the script anywhere
2. Make the script executable: `chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/the_script.sh`
3. Create a service here: `/etc/systemd/system/before-shutdown.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute delete awake user script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/the_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Reload systemctl so that service takes effect : `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Enable the service: `systemctl enable before-shutdown.service`
6. Start the Service: `systemctl start before-shutdown.service`

You can add the steps mentioned above in user data so that it runs automatically and your scrip `the_scrip.sh` can become part of the source code and so can the before-shutdown.service file

Following resources helped me: [Link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)